# Master Page not working on ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net

I'm having trouble with my ASP.NET Webform. All my pages are working perfectly with the master page, but for some reason my ProductItem page isn't accepting the master page. 
Heres my code for ProductItem:

```
 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProductItem.aspx.cs" Inherits="mumsBoutique.ProductItem" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="Content/websiteStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <h1><center>Product Details</center></h1>
<div class="row">
                        <asp:Label ID="productNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Product"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="productItemNumber" runat="server" Text="ProductCode" CssClass="ProductItem_productNumber"></asp:Label>
                    </h3>


                    <h3>
                        <asp:Label ID="productCost" runat="server" Text="£0.00"></asp:Label>
                    </h3>
                <p>
                    <asp:Image ID="productImage" runat="server" />
                </p>

                <h4>Product summary</h4>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="productDescription" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </p>


        <!-- The right colum displays a text box for user to add items to the basket -->

            <h3>Buy Item</h3>
            <p>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
                        <p>
                Quantity: <asp:TextBox ID="itemQuantity" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvItemQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Quantity is required" Text="Please specify the quantity required" ControlToValidate="itemQuantity" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvItemQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid quantity value" Text="Please specify a valid numeric quantity value" ControlToValidate="itemQuantity" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="text-danger" Operator="DataTypeCheck"></asp:CompareValidator>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvItemQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid quantity value" Text="Please specify a quantity value between 1 and 10" ControlToValidate="itemQuantity" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="10" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RangeValidator>
            </p>
           <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddToBasket" runat="server" Text="Add to basket" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" OnClick="btnAddToBasket_Click" />
            </p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

But I don't think the problem is on this particular page. It seems the problem occurs when I run the page from the hyperlink on the Bags.aspx page

```
 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Bags.aspx.cs" Inherits="mumsBoutique.Bags" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="Content/mumsBoutique.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <h1><center>Bags</center></h1>
<div class="row">
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CssClass="table ProductsDataList" DataKeyField="productID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="180px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture", "~/{0}") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("productID", "ProductItem.aspx/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval ("productName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                <br />
                Item Number:
                <asp:Label ID="ItemNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productNumber") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="CostLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cost", "{0:C}") %>' />

                <br />
                <br />
<br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Items.productID, Items.productName, Items.productNumber, Items.picture, Items.cost, Items.categoryID, ItemCategories.Name AS Expr1 FROM ItemCategories INNER JOIN Items ON ItemCategories.categoryID = Items.categoryID WHERE (Items.categoryID = 2)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Would really appreciate any help, been stuck for hours!

Update: Here are some screen shots of the problem I mean. 
[This is the Bags.aspx Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCSqa.jpg) When you click on the hyperlink it takes you to the following
[ProductItem.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHGGB.png)As can be seen the master page isn't being used for some reason. Yet in all other pages it works perfectly fine.

Here is the ProductItem.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;
using mumsBoutique.Models;

namespace mumsBoutique
{
    public partial class ProductItem : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            int _productID = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IList<string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments();

            if (segments != null && segments.Count > 0)
            {
                // Convert the item ID to an integer and store it in the field _itemID
                int.TryParse(segments[0], out _productID);
            }

            // If no item ID is specified, go back to the products page
            if (_productID == 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Products");
            }

            // If _itemID is a valid value, search the database for the matching item
            if (!IsPostBack && _productID > 0)
            {
                // open the connection to the database
                using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {


                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE productId = @productId";
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parameter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@productId", _productID);
                    Item foundItem = context.Database.SqlQuery<Item>(sql, parameter).FirstOrDefault();

                    productNameLabel.Text = foundItem.productName;
                    productItemNumber.Text = foundItem.productNumber;
                    productCost.Text = foundItem.cost.ToString("c");
                    productImage.ImageUrl = "~/" + foundItem.picture;
                    productDescription.Text = foundItem.productDecription;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void btnAddToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if page is valid
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                int qty = 0;

                // Get the quantity from the input field
                qty = int.Parse(itemQuantity.Text);

                // Check if item already exist in basket
                OrderItem basketItem = ShopApp.Instance.GetBasketItem(_productID);

                if (basketItem == null)
                {
                    // item does not currently exist in basket, add new one
                    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {

                        // find the product item (pItem) with ItemId matching what is stored in the variable field (_itemId)
                        Item productItem = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.productID == _productID);
                        basketItem = new OrderItem()
                        {
                            productId = _productID,
                            Quantity = qty,
                            Price = double.Parse(productCost.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency),
                            Item = productItem
                        };
                        ShopApp.Instance.BasketItems.Add(basketItem);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // item already exists in basket, increase the quantity
                    basketItem.Quantity += qty;
                }


                ((SiteMaster)Master).UpdateBasket();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error message ?

Comment: Theres no error message, the page works its just not using the master page.

Comment: Did you check your masterpage and page's paths? And you may have problem because of "~" character in your masterpage's path. So where is masterpage? If its in a folder, you can try with "..\Site.Master"

Comment: The master page is not in any specific folder, all pages are grouped together under the project name. If you look at my original code description above, it was originally without "~". I attempted it as one of the answers mentioned it might have been the problem but it remains in the same state. I have tried "..\Site.Master" and I get this error: 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1009 Unrecognized escape sequence. I am not sure what my error is but I doubt it is anything to do with the path. Thanks for your reply, and I am willing to try anything.

Comment: Okey then could you try "Site.Master" rather than using "~/" characters in path.

Comment: Throws me an error message, I already specified Site.Master as the MasterPageFile.

Comment: I thought all the files are on the root folder. But I think its not. If you can provide more info, people can find a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the productID as a parameter, so try changing `NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("productID", "ProductItem.aspx/{0}") %>'`

to

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("productID", "ProductItem.aspx?productID={0}") %>'
```

Also, you need to move your CSS links to the appropriate place in your master page - you should not be  linking to CSS style sheets from within a page when using a master page, and certainly not from within a ContentPlaceHolder section as you are not overriding any styles. This is more than likely the cause of your problem.

**UPDATE**

I've taken a look at your project and found the following problems, just by eyeballing it (can't run it due to diff DB version, etc):

1. The markup in your master page is badly formed. You are basically doing everything in the head section because **you have no body section**.
2. The link to your style sheet in the master page is outside of the
   HTML document - it should be within the head section. Here is how structure of your master page should look:

   ```
   <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
       CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="mumsBoutique.SiteMaster" %> 
   <!DOCTYPE html>  
   <html lang="en">
   <head runat="server">
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <link href="Content/websiteStyle.css" rel="stylesheet"
           type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
           ...
       </form>
   </body>
   ```
3. Remove the superfluous CSS links from your Bags and ProductItem
   pages - when you have fixed the CSS link in the master page, that is
   all you should need; you're obviously not overriding anything as you are specifying the same style sheet throughout.

Comment: Thanks will try this as soon as i get home :)

Comment: Didn't make any difference :(

Comment: I u[dated the answer but there are still missing pieces in your question. For example, it looks like you are trying to pass productID as a parameter, but I still think we are missing something here... can we see code-behind for the ProductItem page?

Comment: Yes do you prefer me sending it via email?

Comment: Sure, anthony.grace@gmail.com :)